# The import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection cannot be resolved

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

How to solve this problem? I have downloaded and imported the "mysql-connector-java" to my build-path project, but still issue. It seems the library doesn't have the Connection class?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: hmm i didn't found the .Connection from `com.mysql.cj.jdbc`

Comment: Were you intending to use Java Modules?

Comment: yes I want to use the .Connection class from .com.mysql.jdbc jar file

Comment: MySQL Connector/J 8.0.x doesn't have a `com.mysql.jdbc.Connection` class, but even with MySQL Connector/J 5.1.x (which does have it) you shouldn't normally have imported that class. Import `java.sql.Connection` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your referenced library looks correct but you have imported a wrong class. You should import `java.sql.Connection` instead of `com.mysql.jdbc.Connection`.

Some other important imports are as follows:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
```

There are hundreds of good tutorials (e.g. [this](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html)) available on the internet.

Comment: Ah sorry my bad sir, and thank you, now I'm using those libraries that you mentioned it. And its work